# Retrieve Last but one row value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to retrieve the last but one row value in column A/B(Value in Date)

Ex1: Row 3 : last column is AB. I need Row 3 Column AA value (Date) in Row 3 Column C.

Ex 2: Row 4:last column in AS: I need Column AR value (date) in ROw 4 column C.

Ex 3:Row 5:last column in BC: I need Column BB value (date) in ROw 5 column C.

there can b one or 2 blank values.

Please let me know if there are any excel formula to tackle this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please include what you have tried. It looks like your task can be accomplished with VBA

Comment: No... i dont have a least bit of idea on which formula to use for this... i need excel formula not through VBA.

Comment: Take look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/last_value.php) and see if it helps with your problem.

Comment: There is no excel formula for that from what I know. You can build your own function in VBA and call it in spreadsheets as if it was a real formula from Excel.

Comment: Thaanks.. will try and let you know if this VBA is working fine..

Comment: @preethikrishna If any of the answers below helped you, would you mind marking either of them as accepted to bring closure to your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with iteration you could use an array-formula like: (for row 3)

```
=INDIRECT("R3C"&MAX(COLUMN(3:3)*(LEN(3:3)>0))-1, 0)
```

without you need to exclude the cell itself... having it at column `C` it would be something like: (for row 3)

```
=INDIRECT("R3C"&MAX(COLUMN($D3:$ZZ3)*(LEN($D3:$ZZ3)>0))-1, 0)
```

if you want to simply auto fill the formula down then replace the `"R3C"` with `"R"&ROW()&"C"`

> The formulas shown here are array formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you get inclined to VBA, you could try something like this:

```
' In C3 type =GetSecondLastColumnValue()
' This function will keep on checking values on column at a time to the right
' If 3 continuous empty cells are found, it will assume that there are no more
' columns with values after that. The last known cell with value will be identified
' and value of column just to its left will be plugged in to column C
Public Function GetSecondLastColumnValue()

    Dim Looper As Integer
    Looper = 1

    Const NoOfContinuousEmptyColumns As Integer = 3

    Dim m_Address As String, m_LastKnownColumnWithValue
    m_Address = Selection.Address
    m_LastKnownColumnWithValue = m_Address

    Do
        m_Address = Range(m_Address).Offset(0, 1).Address
        If Range(m_Address).Value = "" Then
            Looper = Looper + 1
            If Looper > NoOfContinuousEmptyColumns Then Exit Do
        Else
            Looper = 1
            m_LastKnownColumnWithValue = m_Address
        End If
    Loop

    m_LastKnownColumnWithValue = Range(m_LastKnownColumnWithValue).Offset(0, -1).Address
    GetSecondLastColumnValue = Range(m_LastKnownColumnWithValue).Value

End Function
```

Example:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1  abc def      ab  cd
2  abc def      xy  zx  st
```

In C1, type `=GetSecondLastColumnValue ()` and it will be populated with `ab`.
In C2, type the same formula and it will be populated with `zx`

This is just an example of what you can do with VBA. Do **NOT** use this function in production. It is insanely greedy and slow. It's just an illustration.

This subroutine is much faster:

```
' This method keeps on going to far right till it reaches the end of the columns
' Then it comes back to the last column with value, and hops to the column to its left, and remembers its value
' That value goes in column C. It loops through all rows you specify in startrow and endrow
Sub PopulateColumnC()
    Dim StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer, RowLoop As Integer
    StartRow = 1
    EndRow = 3

    Dim m_Address As String

    For RowLoop = StartRow To EndRow
        Range("A" & RowLoop).Select
        m_Address = Selection.Address
        Do
            Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
            If m_Address = Selection.Address Then
                Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
                Exit Do
            Else
                m_Address = Selection.Address
            End If
        Loop
        m_Address = Range(Selection.Address).Offset(0, -1).Address
        Range("C" & RowLoop).Value = Range(m_Address).Value
    Next

End Sub
```